# How to fix firefox connection untrusted

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, ssl

Firefox gives me connection untrusted for SSL https, and why is that, Chrome shows https in green so, chrome OK, firefox not, why ?

Comment: Which version of FF are you using? Do you get this error message in any particular website?

Comment: 6.0.2 , There are sites that i can log trough https

Comment: Are you sure you are using FF version 6.0.2 & above? because they fixed the problem. Please check here: http://www.mozilla.org/security/announce/2011/mfsa2011-35.html

Comment: just checked, any ideas it is 6.0.2

Comment: I'm not sure how we can fix this problem unless if we file a bug. Please install this plugin & verify : https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/calomel-ssl-validation/. If it works then uninstall and re-install the FF browser if not then file a bug.

Comment: Please follow this link & update you existing FF browser: http://www.spicytricks.com/2011/09/mozilla-firefox-602-releasedsecurity.html

Comment: user969724 it says that WARNING CONNECTION INSECURE red 20%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this:

https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Displaying_web_content_in_an_extension_without_security_issues

Comment: Can't see any issue solving, if u have ideas please share

Answer (score 2):

when i install ff 16.0.2, i seem to have same prob with you(untrusted connection especially firefox addon)..For me, it basically cause by my nod32 antivirus, i try go to setting>protocol filtering>ssl>certificates>untick "add the root certificate to known browser''(make sure ff really close)..then tick it again and click OK..done

Answer (score 0):

I thing you can bypass the warning:

You can tell Firefox to bypass these certificate warnings. You should only bypass the warning if you're sure that the site is legitimate. Legitimate public sites will not ask you to do this. An invalid certificate can be an indication of a web page that will defraud you or steal your identity.

```
1.On the warning page, click Or you can add an exception....
2.Click Add Exception.... The Add Security Exception dialog will appear.
3.Click Get Certificate.
4.Read the text describing the problems with this site.
5.Click Confirm Security Exception if you want to trust the site.
```

http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Secure%20Connection%20Failed
http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Firefox%20cannot%20connect%20securely%20because%20the%20site%20uses%20an%20older%20insecure%20version%20of%20the%20SSL%20protocol

If any of these TS won't work, then try to update to FF V7. Don't forget to file a bug in `bugzilla` with all the necessary information.

Comment: I don't want to work only on my browser i want to work on all PC's browsers .

Comment: @user969724: you didn't ask your question properly. It seems like you a network & it might be a problem with the router(network connection). Please re-write(edit) your question properly.

Answer (score 0):

However if you wish to access sites without accepting the certificate each time, use the add-on skip-cert-error "[https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/skip-cert-error](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/skip-cert-error/)"

Answer (score 0):

I had this weird issue "Your connection is not secure" whereas Chrome works like a charm.

Actually, it is because i let the corporate pac script to manage the proxy setup ticking the option "use system proxy settings". Actually, Firefox don't like it !
When i switch back to the manual proxy settings, all get back to work. 
Of course, you need to known proxy params.

Go & surf ...

Answer (score -1):

Change your Date to current date :D 
I had same issue